# EF Core compiled query fails with InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 7.0.5, with the compiled queries feature, connected to a SQL Server 2019 instance on Linux. This application is an ASP.NET Core MVC application running on Windows.

Compiled query (failing):

```cs
private static readonly Func<ApplicationDbContext, Guid, List<RelatedItem>> _findRelatedPrimaryItems = EF.CompileQuery(
    (ApplicationDbContext database, Guid entityID) =>
        database.RelatedItems
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(ri => ri.PrimaryItemID == entityID)
            .ToList()
    );
```

Calling code:

```cs
public List<RelatedItem> FindRelatedItemsForDocument(Guid documentID) {
    //  This commented out query works fine, but it's not the compiled query I want.
    //List<RelatedItem> items = this.RelatedItems
    //      .AsNoTracking()
    //      .Where(ri => ri.PrimaryItemID == documentID)
    //      .ToList();

    List<RelatedItem> items = _findRelatedPrimaryItems(this, documentID);
    return items;
}
```

Error:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(r => r.PrimaryItemID == __entityID) .ToList()' could not be
> translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I have defined several other compiled queries that work just fine.

Here is an example:

```cs
private static readonly Func<ApplicationDbContext, Guid, Document?> _findDocument = EF.CompileQuery(
    (ApplicationDbContext database, Guid documentID) =>
        database.Documents
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(d => d.DocumentID == documentID)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    );
```

In case it's relevant, the table columns in question are defined as:

RelatedItems

| Column | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| RelatedItems.RelatedItemID | PK bigint identity not null |
| RelatedItems.PrimaryItemID | uniqueidentifier not null |
| RelatedItems.SecondayItemID | uniqueidentifier not null |

Documents

| Column | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| Documents.DocumentID | PK uniqueidentifier not null |
| Documents.Title | nvarchar(max) not null |

There is no database relationship between these two tables.

I don't see any difference between the working query and the failing query.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: The preview showed the markdown tables just fine.  Not sure why the question is all messed up.

Comment: You need to put an empty line between the title (table name) and the beginning of the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.  That was dumb.

Changing the compiled query signature to return an `IEnumerable<>` instead of a `List<>` makes it work great.